# How can I transfer a PHP-based Facebook session to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've taken a look at the answer provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445232/why-doesnt-facebook-use-jquery-or-similar) question, and it's gotten me even further from where I want to be!

I've integrated Facebook Login in my app using the Facebook PHP SDK, and it's working beautifully (I'm using with Laravel and it's just great!).

I'm looking to transfer this Facebook session to Javascript so that I can make a few AJAX calls to the API. I have the session in a PHP variable, but I'm just wondering what I can do to pass its contents over to JS and initialise the FB SDK using them. Does anyone have any simplified suggestions for how I can achieve this?

Comment: As far as i know this is not possible. But maybe I am wrong. **UPDATE** Seems that I could be wrong. You can manually set the AuthResponse object when initializing the js sdk: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [facebooks docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) this **could** work:

PHP:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

JS:

```
FB.init({
    appId  : '<?php echo $yourAppId; ?>',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '<?php echo $signed_request["access_token"]; ?>',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest: '<?php echo $_REQUEST["signed_request"]; ?>',
        userID:'<?php echo $facebook->getUser(); ?>'
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: I'm getting `Undefined index: signed_request` for `$_REQUEST['signed_request']`. Do I need to set this first, or should I use `$signed_request`?

Comment: This should be set by Facebook on first request of the app frame if you even are in one. Otherwise php sdk doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: That wasn't working, but I did figure out what I needed. I turns out that I didn't need the Facebook session. All I needed was the access token to call the API. All I did was `echo "<script>var fb_access_token = '".$fb->getAccessToken()."';</script>";` in PHP, and then `FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,picture.width(250).height(250),username', {access_token : fb_access_token}, function(response){});` in JS. Simple. :)

Comment: Ah well ok, I've been thinking too complicated I guess. ;)